# Is there a pattern/technique that supports unit testing shared "initiating flows"

Tags: corda

Is there a pattern/technique that supports unit testing shared "initiating flows" that have been implemented in a "shared cordapp.jar"  that have multiple corresponding private "responding flows " each of which is implemented in its own "private party name cordapp.jar"  ? Hope this question makes sense.
Terminology is as per [Can either side of a Corda flow exist in separate Cordapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835229/can-either-side-of-a-corda-flow-exist-in-separate-cordapps).
Thanks for all info.
John

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You just have to define a dummy response flow and register it on each node as an initiated flow:

```
@InitiatedBy(MyInitiator::class)
class MyTestResponder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // Implement flow logic here.
    }
}

class FlowTests {
    lateinit var network: MockNetwork
    lateinit var a: StartedNode<MockNode>
    lateinit var b: StartedNode<MockNode>

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        setCordappPackages("my.package")
        network = MockNetwork()
        val nodes = network.createSomeNodes(2)
        a = nodes.partyNodes[0]
        b = nodes.partyNodes[1]
        nodes.partyNodes.forEach {
            it.registerInitiatedFlow(MyTestResponder::class.java)
        }
        network.runNetwork()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        network.stopNodes()
        unsetCordappPackages()
    }

    @Test
    fun `example test`() {
        val flow = MyInitiator(b.info.chooseIdentity())
        val future = a.services.startFlow(flow).resultFuture
        network.runNetwork()
        future.getOrThrow()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.